# Insert characters into each line of a text file

Tags: file, text, batch-file, insert, character

Using a batch file I need to insert characters into each line of an existing text file. Write the results to a new text file that will be used to populate a database. The inserted characters will become delimiters to arrange the data in it proper order.

Sample:
File as it exists today:

```
AAAAAAAAA~ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA~BB~ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA~BB~CCCC~ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA~BBB~CC~ZZZ
```

Desired results:

```
AAAAAAAAA~~~~ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA~BB~~~ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA~BB~CCCC~~ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA~BBB~CC~~ZZZ
```

Appearance after delimiters are triggered:

```
Part Num    Rev    Stat   Type        
AAAAAAAAA                 ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA   BB            ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA   BB     CC     ZZZ  
AAAAAAAAA   BBB    CC     ZZZ
```

Note:
The first field is always 9 characters
The last field is always 3 characters
I’m using the tilde as the field delimiter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic how many delimiters need to be inserted.

Comment: Is it possible to have records in the format `AAAAAAAAA~CC~ZZZ` or `AAAAAAAAA~CCCC~ZZZ` in any lines? (i.e. without a revision)

Comment: It is not very clear why tildes had to be added to the last to lines. Based on the tabular form of your sample data, there are four fields, but the delimited lines suggest there are five. Either way, is it correct to assume that: 1) the first field and the last field are always present, 2) the maximum number of fields is fixed, and 3) if there are fewer fields than the maximum, the absent (or *empty*) ones are always those preceding the last field?

Comment: The number of delimiters will "always" be 3 and I apologize for the error  made during my effort to create and post the examples. As I mentioned, field 1 and field 4 will be constant; 9 characters and 3 characters respectively. Field 2 and field 3 will vary in length, however, based on the historical entries in the database field 2 is usually 2 characters in length and field 3 is 4 characters, but like all ., but can does change. I appreciate the time you spent and your response.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.
Usage: `mapper {sourfile} {targetfile}`

`mapper.cmd`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~1" == "" (
  echo No source file specified.
  goto :eof
)
if not exist "%~1" (
  echo Source file not found.
  goto :eof
)
if "%~2" == "" (
  echo No target file specified.
  goto :eof
)
if exist "%~2" (
  echo Target file is already exist.
  goto :eof
)
rem>"%~2"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=~" %%a in (%~1) do (
  if "%%b" == "" (
    echo %%a~~~~>>"%~2"
  ) else (
    if "%%c" == "" (
      echo %%a~~~~%%b>>"%~2"
    ) else (
      if "%%d" == "" (
        echo %%a~%%b~~~%%c>>"%~2"
      ) else (
        if "%%e" == "" (
          echo %%a~%%b~%%c~~%%d>>"%~2"
        ) else (
          echo %%a~%%b~%%c~%%d~%%e>>"%~2"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```